# Z axis nexus 4 incorrect. Software or hardware?

Tags: nexus-4, sensors

I noticed that before I upgraded to Lollipop my z axis of the lge accelerometer of the nexus 4 used to be 10.2 m/s^2 (which was wrong but closer to accurate). After I upgraded it is now 10.6. Is this a problem with nexus 4's in general? Can any other nexus 4 owners confirm as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my values. Mine reports slightly lower numbers (9.2).
I believe `LGE Accelerometer Sensor` field shows raw data from the sensor. It's normal that it's not super accurate. More importantly look at `Gravity` and `Linear Acceleration` fields in both mine and your screenshot. These fields show expected values. This means software compensates for sensor inaccuracy well.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the orientation of the phone and the values will change. The value of z axis at 10m/sec^2 is normal when phone is lying horizontal to the ground.

Comment: All other axis show 9.8 (correct) when aligned perfectly perpendicular to their axis